# Need to return value of 1 if EXACT MATCH is found

Tags: excel, vba

Quick question.. I know it must be simple.. but I want to alter the code below, that when an EXACT MATCH is found within a spreadsheet 1, range (column A, 2 to last row), of a cell within spreadsheet 2 (column A, starting at line 2, to last row,  to cycle cell by cell), it returns the value of "1" in spreadsheet 1, to the column designated by a variable, (as it corresponds to a month chosen by the User in a form/combo box).

I need it to be AN EXACT MATCH. This works.. but does not look to match exact.  I cannot have skewed results as these are part numbers. In other words.. 
12345-6 should not match 12345-61, and that is what is occurring, as I do not know how to match entire cell contents in VBA.. well I know it is LookIn, LookAt, but I don't know how to incorporate the proper statements into my existing code with this variable.

```
Dim CycleCountCell As Integer
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set wb1 = Workbooks(vFileName1) 'ABC Matrix File
Set wb2 = Workbooks(vFileName2) 'ABC Transacations by Item
Set sht = wb1.Worksheets(1) 'ABC Matrix File
Set sht1 = wb2.Worksheets(1) 'ABC Transactions by Item

lRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Select Case ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value
    Case "January": CycleCountCell = 22
    Case "February": CycleCountCell = 24
    Case "March": CycleCountCell = 26
    Case "April": CycleCountCell = 4
    Case "May": CycleCountCell = 6
    Case "June": CycleCountCell = 8
    Case "July": CycleCountCell = 10
    Case "August": CycleCountCell = 12
    Case "September": CycleCountCell = 14
    Case "October": CycleCountCell = 16
    Case "November": CycleCountCell = 18
    Case "December": CycleCountCell = 20
End Select

'Execute Match (Vlookup)
Msgbox "Preparing update to Cycle Count for " & ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value & ".", vbInformation, "ABC Matrix Macro"

'Display customized message on Excel Status Bar letting user know lookup is in progress

Application.StatusBar = "ABC Matrix Macro is updating all " & lRow & " " & "cells within" & ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1 & "column with Cycle Count.  " & "This process may take a few minutes..."

On Error Resume Next
For i = 2 To lRow
If sht.Cells(i, 1).value <> "" Then
    Set rng = sht1.Range("A:A").Find(sht.Cells(i, 1).value)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
         sht.Cells(i, CycleCountCell).value = ("1")
    End If
End If
Next
```

Comment: Sorry, why use a macro? Does a `VLOOKUP()` or `Index/Match` not do the trick?

Comment: Application.Match(ref,range,0)  the 0 (third variable) makes it have to be exact.  That output is a number, so if the number is >0, value = 1.

Comment: This is a snip it of the code, there are 20k rows this cycles through, and it preforms many other actions in the macro overall. It is to automate a report that is being preformed manually.

Comment: @BruceWayne - We meet again Batman..   This is the same macro I have been working on.. it completes many other steps.. this is at the tail end of where I am so far.. I just ended it, to test my progress over all. I still have about 8 other steps to go..

Comment: I think `Match()` would be faster, but FYI: `Find()` remembers any previous settings from the last time it was used, so if you don't specify (eg) `LookAt:=xlWhole` as a parameter when you call it in VBA, then you may get unexpected results  - i.e here it seems like it's using `xlPart` by default.

Comment: That is EXACTLY what is happening @TimWilliams. I tested that by manually setting it to match entire cell contents, and executed the macro.. worked like a charm.  Then went back in and changed selection, poof.  started putting 1's on anything "close" to the number and the number.  I would love anything that would work faster..  Again, this is taking a report that is about 20K entries and growing, and taking a report produced monthly (around 200 lines) and putting a 1 if the part number appears on the report. No room for error.

Comment: Are you working with a clean sheet every time this runs?  So anything that's not "1" would be empty?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. This takes a file and updates the exact same file month by month (so a file would contain 12 columns representing all months), but what column would reflect the 1's would be changed month to month, by what the user selects in the combo box. The variable then translates into the column reference that corresponds to the value they selected.  It takes a report of part numbers which usually has 200 rows, and if the part is represented on that report, it places a 1 (no matter how many times the same part may appear), in the annual report. but it has to be EXACT.

Comment: and yes.. at the end of running the macro, any number that does not match would be empty. It only needs to place a 1 when it matches, anything else - blank.. no N/A, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested but may work faster:

```
Dim d, m

With sht
    d = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(lRow, "A")).Value
End With

For i = 1 To UBound(d, 1) '<<< EDIT
    If Len(d(i, 1)) > 0 Then
        m = Application.Match(d(i, 1), sht1.Range("A:A"), 0)
        d(i, 1) = IIf(IsError(m), "", "1")
    End If
Next

sht.Cells(2, CycleCountCell).Resize(UBound(d, 1), 1).Value = d
```

Comment: Runtime 9 out of range on  If Len(d(i, 1)) > 0 Then

Comment: !! THANK YOU! Now.. I have a question.. after discovering that this was not matching exact, I have used this same block of code in two other macros (which tie into this project).  I am not starting to rethink if it is actually producing the end result by matching exact, or saying.. "meh, close enough.. " and returning a value. In the other examples I am comparing again, columns A, (part number) but in this instance, if matched, returning indexed columns, and placing the value in the annual report, based on a variable. If it matches, it returns 3 values from the same row.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is here?  Maybe start a new post and flesh it out a bit.

Comment: It takes a few minutes to work, nothing too crazy, but if I am not using the best approach, for processing speed, and well.. I would be interested in changing that.  I had it posted in another question on here (which I am not sure if I deleted). Can I possibly tag you in that, for your input? I don't want to take advantage of your kindness.. @tim Williams

Comment: Sure, tag me in.